# How to add a link to a tr element to open a turbo frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, turbo

In my code Ive got an iteration, which outputs `<tr>` elements with regarding content. Table elements in HTML are pretty limited so you cant wrap `<a href="">`s around them. Insted there is a workaround in jquery/or whatever JS you are using like

```
  $("tr[data-link]").on("click", function() {
    window.location = $(this).parent().data("link");
  });
```

which can be used to turn `<tr>` into clickable elements which open up links. However this does not work for turbo frame links. If i use something like

```
<tr data-link="<%= project_path(@project) %>"
  data-turbo-frame="project_sidebar">
...
```

it just opens up the link .. as expected, because `window.location` does exactly this.

I tried stuff like `Turbo.visit($(this).parent().data("link"));` in my js as well which don't work at all.

Is there a way to tell the `<tr>` to open up a turbo frame via js instead of being a "real" link?

Comment: Try using CSS properties `display: table;` `display: table-row;` `display: table-cell;` You can make anything behave like a table element. So you can use straight links.

Comment: interesting approach. I never thought of it that way to be honest. that would solve a lot of problems but I was too lazy to refactor all the tables of my app to be divs or sth. will try it out now.

Comment: If you're up for re-doing the html, then I suggest doing it the modern way, with css grid.